# GLM in R - using lm instead of lmer/lme

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have a data obtained from an experiment where subjects were exposed to different stimuli (condition) and gave responses for each of those stimuli. So, my predictor here is the 'condition' and the outcome is the 'response' I also have two continious variables which will act as covariates.

Before starting the analysis, I created a document where I described in detail what kind of analysis (statistical models etc) that I will run. Basically, I noted in the document that I will conduct  a general linear model (GLM) with factor condition and two additional continious covariates. I implied that I will use GLM in the regression framework to be able to work with continious variables. And the idea is that I should stick to this plan and not change it anymore

Now I am worried if I came up with a wrong analysis plan. For such data, it is often recommended using lmer (or lme?) function and add + (1|ID) at the end of the formula to account for within subject variance. My concern is that if I use lmer funciton, than this means that I am running a mixed model and not running a  GLM (I guess?). Can I still run a GLM by using the lm() function in such design somehow?

It could be the case that I am overall confused with the terminology...

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. Can you explain what the response variable is and how it is measured ? Note that GLM is usually used for Generalised Linear Model, not General Linear Model (they are very different).  If you have repeated measures then you do need to account for that. Using a mixed model (eg `lme` or `lmer`) is one way to do so. Another way is to use `lm` and add the grouping variable (ID) as a fixed effect, though this is not very satisfactory when you have many groups.

Comment: I appreciate the comment! But I resolved the issue after having some talks with my supervisors... But interesting to see that you can account for subject variance using lm function, I did not know that.